# grep or awk to cut 2 different lines

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have this report file below called *monitor.log*

```
switch#sh mac address-table int g1/0/1
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
 110    000f.ffff.ffff    STATIC      drop
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 1
switch#sh mac address-table int g1/0/4
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
 110    000f.ffff.ffff    STATIC      drop
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 1
switch#sh mac address-table int g1/0/3
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
 110    000f.ffff.ffff    STATIC      drop
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 1
```

I want a command using either grep , awk or sed to show only those fields and save to a file i.e:

```
int g1/0/1 drop 
int g1/0/2 drop
int g1/0/3 drop
```

Comment: Why do you run the command for one and one interface?  I would have just run `sh mac address-table` to get the `mac` from all interface in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS='switch#sh' '$3 {print $3,$4,$21}' monitor.log
int g1/0/1 drop
int g1/0/4 drop
int g1/0/3 drop
```

To restrict the report to `drop` entries:

```
awk -v RS='switch#sh' '$21=="drop" {print $3,$4,$21}' monitor.log
```

#### Handling tables with multiple lines

Suppose that the input file looks like:

```
$ cat monitor.log2
switch#sh mac address-table int g1/0/1
Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan Mac Address Type Ports
---- ----------- -------- -----
110 000f.ffff.ffff STATIC drop
200 000f.ffff.ffff STATIC drop
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 1 
switch#sh mac address-table int g1/0/2
          Mac Address Table
```

Then use:

```
$ awk '/switch#sh/{a=$4" "$5} /----/,/Total Mac Addresses/ {if ($4=="drop")print a,$4}' monitor.log2
int g1/0/1 drop
int g1/0/1 drop
```

Comment: How I filter it only by  '\drop\' ?

Comment: @CDm OK.  I added a drop-only option to the answer.

Comment: I forget that some of the records have 2 records how to filter those? Thank you...

switch#sh mac address-table int g1/0/1
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
 110    000f.ffff.ffff    STATIC      drop
 200    000f.ffff.ffff    STATIC      drop
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 1

Comment: I figure this out with the following :
awk -v RS='switch#sh' '$21=="drop" {print $3,$4,$18,$19,$21}' monitor.log
awk -v RS='switch#sh' '$25=="drop" {print $3,$4,$22,$23,$25}' monitor.log

Comment: Should be mentioned that you need `gnu awk` for multiple characters in RS: `RS='switch#sh'`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep, paste, bash

```
paste -d" " <(grep -oP '(?<=mac address-table ).+' monitor.log) \
            <(grep -oP '\d+\s+[[:xdigit:].]+\s+\w+\s+\K.+' monitor.log)
```

With GNU sed, paste

```
sed -rn '
    s/.*mac address-table //p
    s/\s+[[:digit:]]+\s+[[:xdigit:].]+\s+[[:alpha:]]+\s+//p
' monitor.log | paste -d" " - -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^switch#sh/,/^Total/ {
   /^switch#sh mac address-table / {s///;h;}
   /[[:space:]]*drop$/ {g;s/$/ drop/p;}
   }' YourFile
```

- if order is important, a pipe sort is easier
- assume to print only if *drop* appear in section of the switch entry